# Xaml Wpf Snake game

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, snake-game

I'm doing a game in Xaml WPF and I didn't really choose the tools and languages.
It's to be hidden in a really big app with a lot of code.

The whole snake takes place in a simple xaml canvas and xaml.cs file
[here](https://github.com/Jebik/XAMLSnake/blob/master/XAMLSnake/XAMLSnake/XAMLSnakeWindow.xaml.cs).

Actually, the snake became really laggy after being taller than 20 part, and even before the speed is absolutely not constant.

I don't know a lot about game programming but I'm doing software for a while now. How can I improve this game, make speed less dependent on snake size, and make it lag way less with the same computer perf?

I think the more important is the paintSnake method called every timer Tick.

```
private void paintSnake(Point currentposition)
{
    cleanSnake();
    paintSnakeHead(currentposition);
    paintSnakeBody(currentposition);
}
private void cleanSnake()
{
    var count = paintCanvas.Children.Count;
    var toDel = count - (NbBonus + 1);
    paintCanvas.Children.RemoveRange(NbBonus + 1, toDel);
}
private void paintSnakeHead(Point currentposition)
{
    var rot = GetRotation();
    RotateTransform aRotateTransform = new RotateTransform();
    aRotateTransform.CenterX = 0.5;
    aRotateTransform.CenterY = 0.5;
    aRotateTransform.Angle = rot;
    _headBrush.RelativeTransform = aRotateTransform;
    Rectangle headRect = new Rectangle();
    headRect.Fill = _headBrush;
    headRect.Height = headSize;
    headRect.Width = headSize;
    Canvas.SetTop(headRect, currentposition.Y);
    Canvas.SetLeft(headRect, currentposition.X);
    //On decale tout les point du snake
    snakePoints.Insert(0, currentposition);
    paintCanvas.Children.Add(headRect);
    int count = snakePoints.Count;
    // Restrict the tail of the snake
    if (count > length)
    {
        snakePoints.RemoveAt(length);
    }
}
private int GetRotation()
{
    switch (direction)
    {
        case (int)MOVINGDIRECTION.DOWNWARDS:
            return 180;
        case (int)MOVINGDIRECTION.UPWARDS:
            return 0;
        case (int)MOVINGDIRECTION.TOLEFT:
            return 270;
        case (int)MOVINGDIRECTION.TORIGHT:
            return 90;
        default:
            return 0;
    }
}
private void paintSnakeBody(Point currentposition)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < snakePoints.Count; i++)
    {
        //On ne dessinne un cercle que tout les headsize position
        if (i % headSize == 0)
        {
            Rectangle bodyRect = new Rectangle();
            bodyRect.Fill = _bodyBrush;
            bodyRect.Height = headSize;
            bodyRect.Width = headSize;
            Canvas.SetTop(bodyRect, snakePoints[i].Y);
            Canvas.SetLeft(bodyRect, snakePoints[i].X);
            paintCanvas.Children.Add(bodyRect);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Its 330 line not to big for a snippet? :S

Comment: Personally, it is not a problem if your code is on GitHub, but the policy of this website states you must include it on your question, otherwise more reputed users will close your question.

Comment: Format left please

Comment: I am wondering if paint a grid and then just fill in or clear would not be faster?

Comment: Where is snakePoints defined?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going to review only the code in your post.

---

You don't use WPF as you have to. In WPF you don't need to perform clear/draw sequence. The right way is to use MVVM and update coordinates of the snake's blocks in view-model. In XAML you will have `ItemsControl` with `Canvas` as its panel. `ItemsSource` should be bound to collection of blocks and each item should have bindings for `Canvas.Top` and `Canvas.Left`.

In fact each item will be wrapped to `ContentPresenter` where there is no your bindings to coordinates, so you can consider to write your custom `Canvas`-based panel which will search for coordinates in each child.

I'm just describing the right way you should work with WPF, there are variants how you'll implement all this stuff.

---

This naming of enum and its fields is wrong:

```cs
MOVINGDIRECTION.DOWNWARDS
MOVINGDIRECTION.UPWARDS
MOVINGDIRECTION.TOLEFT
...
```

You should follow [naming guidelines](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions) for types and public members:

```
MovingDirection.Down
MovingDirection.Up
MovingDirection.Left
...
```

---

What is the purpose of casting enum values to `int`?

> ```
> case (int)MOVINGDIRECTION.DOWNWARDS:
> ```

Yes, I see on your GitHub repo that all your direction fields have type of `int`. But why? Let those fields be of `MovingDirection` type.

---

Also I suggest to go away from your `switch` and use `Dictionary`:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<MovingDirection, int> RotationAngles =
    new Dictionary<MovingDirection, int>
{
    [MovingDirection.Down] = 180,
    [MovingDirection.Up] = 0,
    [MovingDirection.Left] = 270,
    [MovingDirection.Right] = 90,
};

private int GetRotation()
{
    return RotationAngles.TryGetValue(direction, out var angle)
        ? angle
        : 0;
}
```

But it's just another way. `switch` is not a problem in your case since there are only 4 possible directions and this situation will not be changed in the future.

Comment: It's the first time i post to code review and i'm surprise because this actually help a lot.
So about naming and dictionary i will change this because its so much clear.

And about moving canvas element i have think about it but not done it already because i must change a bit my way of thinking. But i will do this tonight and see if performance are better

Comment: And about why i have int.... Not real reason i  decide to use a int 0 for no direction instead of adding enum None... Bad choice i must change that to no need int for direction in my case

Comment: @Jebik `None` is a good choice so don't be afraid of it :)

Comment: I have change the code a lot since this morning... But i can't really test it.

I think its more optimize. But i would like to have a review in the whole code to help me continue to improve it a bit.

And about what i saw in help center it's not really appropriate here. Are they any site in stackExchange community where i can get this? 

I have stopped use int. stopped deleting and redraw every part every tick. 

Added a notion of fluidit to move 1/4Box instead of 1 pixel each Timer Tick....  But i think it still have some big mistake for a first game.

Comment: You are still not using MVVM. It is the big mistake in WPF app development :)

Comment: I understand but MVVM require more file no? I try to hide this in a big project the xaml file is already to much in fact i would love to only have one CS file... But if its possible to describe xaml in Cscharp and do MvvM in one single file... Then i would like to know how to do that for my snake.

Comment: Yes, MVVM requires more files. But it is the right way. Separating components of an app is a very important part of development since it improves readbility and code navigation. **Don't try to put all your code in one file.** It's a dangerous way which can make your code messy very quickly.

Comment: Instead of a dictionary, he should just use an enum with the numeric angle values.

Comment: In my opinion it is a bad practice to use enums as `int`s. I always prefer to use dictionaries if I need to link enum values with some objects. Also, today angles are `int`s, tomorrow they can be `double`s.